# Lua string match with conditional

Tags: lua, match, matching

Can anyone troubleshoot this. I cant figure out why the if statement is false and not printing d1 when run.

````
    channel = "2.245"
    d1, d2, d3, d4, d5 = channel:match("(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)")
    if (d1==2) then
        print (d1)
    end
    print (d1)
    print (d2)
    print (d3)
    print (d4)
    print (d5)
    ```
````

Comment: In Lua `2` not equals to `"2"`